# Animating opacity doesn't work in IE or Opera

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opera, opacity

I'm experimenting with jQuery plugins. I have this code to fade in a "lightbox":

```
$('#cleverbox')
    .css({ opacity:0, visibility:'visible' })
    .animate( {opacity:1}, 2000 );
```

It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but in IE (7 and 8) and Opera the element just appears rather than being faded in. There are a bunch of similar questions on SO but I have yet to find a solution that works.

I have an [example page](http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/cleverbox). I'm also having a few other problems:

1. In Internet Explorer (7 and 8), the first thumbnail never displays the lightbox (the `onload` event never fires).
2. In IE7, the code to fix the ClearType bug doesn't work. `$(this).css( 'opacity', '' )` should remove the opacity style (in this case, the 'filter' property) but it doesn't remove it. In IE's dev tools it still has `style="filter: ;"`
3. In Opera, it never runs after it has loaded once. In other words, if an image is in the browser cache the `onload` event never fires.

Comment: Things you probably already know: IE doesn't support CSS opacity; Opera may hide it behind a custom prefix because CSS opacity is still in the CSS3 draft, not a final spec. I don't know if JQuery tries to emulate these.

IE will disable ClearType if an Opacity is set via a DX filter.

Comment: jQuery overcomes cross-browser compatibilities like this (that's one of the main reasons to use it) - Opera supports opacity just fine, and in IE is uses the filter property. As for ClearType, the code above is meant to fix that bug, which it does in IE8, but not 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for the bug in Opera, thanks to the Opera community. I had this:

```
var imgLoad = new Image();
imgLoad.src = linkUrl;
imgLoad.onload = function() {
    //do some stuff here
}
```

However, if the image is in the browser cache it never fires because the loading part comes before the onload function. The solution is to move the `src` assignment below the onload function:

```
var imgLoad = new Image();
imgLoad.onload = function() {
    //do some stuff here
}
imgLoad.src = linkUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping opacity values in `'`, i.e. `$(something).animate({opacity:'1'});`? Works for me everytime.